# How to use mutate_if with a function

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I want to transform dataframe `d` into the result below (`result`) using the function `replace_by_sym`. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- data.frame(dir = c(-1,1,-1,1,1), a = rep(100,5), b = 105:109, c = 108:112)

replace_by_sym <- function(x){
  x <- x * (-1) + 200
}

d %>%
  mutate_if(dir=-1, vars(a:c),
            funs(replace_by_sym(.))) -> result
```

to obtain

```
   dir   a   b   c
1  -1   100  95  92
2   1   100 106 109
3  -1   100  93  90
4   1   100 108 111
5   1   100 109 112
```

Comment: If you're making a comparison, you want `dir == -1`, not `dir = -1`

Comment: `mutate_if()` operates on columns that meet your predicate, not rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done with `ifelse`

```
d %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs( ifelse (dir == -1, (dir * .)  + 200, .)))
#   dir   a   b   c
#1  -1 100  95  92
#2   1 100 106 109
#3  -1 100  93  90
#4   1 100 108 111
#5   1 100 109 112
```

---

Or with `case_when`

```
d %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(a:c), funs(case_when(dir == -1 ~ (dir * .) + 200, 
                                       TRUE ~ as.numeric(.))))
```